# Shuffle two Strings recursively to make another String

Tags: java, string, recursion, static, boolean

I'm trying to create a method shuffle `(String stri, String str2, String str3)` that returns a boolean and take two Strings and "shuffles" them to make a third String, but I'm trying to do it recursively, which is kind of tough for me to think about. I want to return true if `str1` and `str2`can be shuffled and return false if they can't be shuffled.

For example, if `str1 = "tv"` and `str2 = "aol"`, the method might return `taovl`.

I also plan to test the method out as well as create another helper method to make it more efficient, but that's easy.

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically do you kneed help with?

Comment: How do you define if a `String` can be "shuffled"?

Comment: I need help finding the base cases, but also need help with calling the recursive method.

Comment: Passing the third String to your method will not work. You need your method to RETURN the generated String.

Comment: Seems like a simple single loop will do this. I can't imagine how recursion would be at all desirable.

Comment: looks like there is nothing to do with recursion. Try to specify more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by simply creating three integer variables to go through the indices of all three strings and checking to see if a a letter at any index matches the same order of `s3`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab3{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str;
    System.out.print("Enter String: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    str = sc.nextLine();
    String res = revRec3(str);
    System.out.println(res);
}

public static String revRec3(String str)
{
    if (str.length() <= 1)
       return str;
   else{
       String first = str.substring(0, str.length() / 3);
       String second = str.substring(str.length() / 3, ((2 * str.length()) / 3));
       String third = str.substring((2 * str.length()) / 3, str.length());

       return revRec3(third)+revRec3(second)+revRec3(first);
   }
}
}
```

try doing something like this. This Program splits a String into 3 pieces and then reverses them using recursion.